# Add count for new registered user in Users tab

Tags: wp-admin, users

Is there a way or hooks that I can use to add counter in Users tab for new registered users like this?. http://prntscr.com/k1bxpn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can use `admin_menu` hook to loop through menu items and add span with notification. There are two classes that WP uses for these notifications `update-plugins` and `awaiting-mod`. The second one looks more appropriate in this case, I guess...

Here's some code:

```
function add_user_menu_notification() {
    global $menu;

    $user_count = count_users();  // get whatever count you need
    $user_count = $user_count['avail_roles']['administrator'];

    if ( $user_count ) {
        foreach ( $menu as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $menu[$key][2] == 'users.php' ) {
                $menu[$key][0] .= ' <span class="awaiting-mod">' . $user_count . '</span>';
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_user_menu_notification' );
```

Comment: thank's man, love it. Btw what if I have an ACF for a user with pending and approved value, and I want to display in the counter the number of pending users?

Comment: Just change two lines that are getting count of users...